# iOS5 Mobile Safari serving mp3s by using php

Tags: php, iphone, ios, mp3, mobile-safari

I host a site for marching band that I work for.  I have a fully functioning members section with login.  I have a .htaccess folder that protects my mp3s from being hot/direct linked.  I can get the files to play in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, but not on my iPhone!

I am serving the content by using headers in a php file which in turn create a html5 audio tag to serve the content. I have tried the readfile() in php with no success.

php file bellow: (minus the security check)

```
$_GET['f'] = "privatefolder/" . $_GET['f'];
$filename = $_GET['f'];
$filesize = @filesize($filename);

$len = strlen( $filename );
$shortlen = $length - 1;
header( 'Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$shortlen.'/'.$len);

header("Last-Modified: ".filemtime($filename));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");//mpeg
header("Etag: W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d");
header("Content-Description: {$filename}");
header("Content-length: {$filesize}");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=button.mp3");
header("X-Pad: avoid browser bug");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Connection: close");

echo "<audio controls='controls'><source src='".file_get_contents($_GET['f'])."' type='audio/mp3' /></audio>";
exit;
```

This code works well in all of the main browsers, but on my iPhone, Mobile Safari locks up and crashes when trying to open a page!

What am I missing? I'm assuming it is a header issue and the way that quicktime "downloads/streams."  I have been battling this for 2 weeks, tried every solution I could find! Help please!!!

*just a side note: I've opened the page in the Opera Mini Browser, and it sends the link over to safari and plays it in quicktime with no issues?!?!? so I know it is possible!

Answer (score 1):

It works on iOS4, it fails on iOS5.
I think the extension has to be "mp3" to work as mp3...

Answer (score 0):

You can't send headers making it seem to be an `mp3` file and include HTML at the same time. I'm shocked it works in any browsers at all.

Your HTML should be something like `<audio><source src="/path/to/mp3.php"></audio>` where `mp3.php` has the headers and outputs the contents of the `mp3` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I originally tried it that way and for whatever reason it didnt work.  It seems you have to clear your cache and restart Safari to get it to work.  So here's where I am at.  That method works fine for Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox.  [Test Link](http://www.pvband.org/testlink1.php) And in Mobile Safari it says cannot read file. I'm really not too concerned with Firefox.  I usually force a download of these files to my students, but I really really really want this to work in Mobile Safari on an iphone. Any ideas?